# How to get the fractional part of the seconds in UTCTime using time.h

Tags: c++, c, windows, utc, time.h

I want to get the system time including fractional part of the seconds. Is it possible in standard c (ANSI C)?
If not then tell me some libraries for window OS so that I make it possible. In Linux I have the following code with work fine for me.

```
 #include <sys/time.h>                                                                
 #include <time.h>                                                                    
 #include <stdlib.h>                                                                  
 #include <stdio.h>                                                                  

 int main(void)                                                                       
 {                                                                                    
   char buffer[30];                                                                   
   struct timeval tv;                                                                 

   time_t curtime;                                                                    



   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);                                                           
   curtime=tv.tv_sec;                                                                 

   strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));                           
   printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);                                               

   return 0;                                                                          


   }
```

Output is

12-25-2009 11:09:18.35443541

Kindly help me, how is it possible for window OS. IF ANSI C doesn't allow me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C does not provide sub-second resolution timing.

POSIX does provide sub-second resolution timing - in fact, a number of different ways of doing it, including `gettimeofday()` which you show.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <wtypes.h>
int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME t;
    GetSystemTime(&t);
    int year = t.wYear;
    int month = t.wMonth;
    int day = t.wDay;
    int hour = t.wHour;
    int minute = t.wMinute;
    int second = t.wSecond;
    int second_fraction = t.wMilliseconds;
   return 0;
}
```

Couple of points about performance if it is important to you:

1) `gettimeofday()` is quite fast and if is used in a few threads it doesn't cause worsenig of performance

2) Inside `localtime()` there is a call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` (probably because it needs some system settings like daytime). So when you use it extensively in a multithreaded application there might performance problems

Comment: @skwllsp:- Kindly tell me the ref. or header file which i have to include for SYSTEMTIME and GetSystemTime....!

Comment: Thanks Skwllsp, I have tried your code but its doesn't give me accurate result.

Comment: This code `int second_fraction = t.wMilliseconds/1000;` should not divide by a thousand.  That wlll cause it to always be zero.  Just use wMilliseconds directly.

Comment: @wallyk 2. Right, I just use code from my program where it was assigned to `double`. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code

```
printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);
```

will work most of the time but it is not correct for small tv.tv_usec values.

If tv.tv_usec is 123, it will print `HH:MM:SS.123` when it should print `HH:MM:SS.000123`

Try this:

```
printf("%s%.6ld\n", buffer, tv.tv_usec);
```